# Filter orders by product in admin

Tags: plugins

I'm setting up Woocommerce store for a client who is selling tickets to multiple different live shows.

On the night of a show, the box office manager needs to be able to view only orders that contain one specific product (the show).

Does anyone know of a plugin that would allow a store manager to either view all orders that contain a specific product, or download a csv of those orders (ideally both)?

Barring that, if anyone has had to do something similar and has any insights on adding custom filters to the order screen, I would really appreciate your input!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the "Search Orders" box on the top right, just enter the product name.

Exporting those to csv requires a more tailored approach, not sure if [Order/Customer CSV export](http://www.woothemes.com/products/ordercustomer-csv-export/) is up to it (ask WooThemes and they'll be quick to respond)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. That plugin doesn't support filtering by product, but I am a complete idiot, and I didn't think of the search box!